# SecureCoding with Subclasses and CoreData ni swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nssecurecoding

I wanted to implement diferrent possible values within a CoreData field as Transformable and subclasses.
Swift doesn't seem to like my implementation: (the superclass)

```swift
public class ResponseItemValueDTODB: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
  public static let supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true
  ...
}
```

The subclasss:

```swift
class ResponseItemValueTextDTODB: ResponseItemValueDTODB {
  //public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool  = true
  ...
}
```

Now the error: `Class 'xx.ResponseItemValueTextDTODB' has a superclass that supports secure coding, but 'xx.ResponseItemValueTextDTODB' overrides -initWithCoder: and does not override +supportsSecureCoding. The class must implement +supportsSecureCoding and return YES to verify that its implementation of -initWithCoder: is secure coding compliant.`

If i uncomment the line in the subclass, the swift compiler doesn't like it too, with error: `Cannot override with a stored property 'supportsSecureCoding'` on that line

How should i go about making the NSSecureCoding happy?

Comment: Strange, I can't get the first error to occur.